# Deleting a row with a foreign key constraint with a Before Delete TRIGGER in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a table called 'estoque' with a foreign key that references another table called 'produto'. Then I've populated both tables with a few rows.

Here are my tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `produto` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `NOME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `PRECO` float NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `NOME_UNIQUE` (`NOME`)
    );

    CREATE TABLE `estoque` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ID_PRODUTO` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `QUANTIDADE_PRODUTO` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `fk_Estoque_Produto1_idx` (`ID_PRODUTO`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Estoque_Produto1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PRODUTO`)
      REFERENCES `produto` (`ID`)
    );
```

I need 'estoque' to always reference all existing rows on 'product'. So I'e created an AFTER INSERT and an AFTER UPDATE triggers on product:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `cadastrar_novo_produto_no_estoque` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `produto` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO estoque (ID_PRODUTO)
    VALUES (NEW.ID);
```

EDIT: Actually, since I can't alter the 'ID' column on 'produto' because it is a primary key, I've think I don't need the AFTER UPDATE trigger at all. Am I right?

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `atualizar_novo_produto_no_estoque` 
    AFTER UPDATE ON `produto` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE estoque
        SET estoque.ID_PRODUTO = NEW.ID
        WHERE OLD.estoque.ID_PRODUTO = OLD.ID;
```

Now I need a trigger so that every time I delete a row from 'product', it also deletes the corresponding row in 'estoque'.

I've tried creating one like this:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `deletar_produto_inexistente_no_estoque` 
    BEFORE DELETE ON `produto` 
    FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM estoque
        WHERE estoque.ID_PRODUTO = ID;
```

But whenever I try to delete a row from 'produto' I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1175: 1175: You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column. 
SQL Statement:
DELETE FROM `papelaria`.`produto` WHERE (`ID` = '6')
```

So I've tried it with the OLD keyword, as such:

```
        CREATE TRIGGER `deletar_produto_inexistente_no_estoque` 
        BEFORE DELETE ON `produto` 
        FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM estoque
            WHERE OLD.estoque.ID_PRODUTO = OLD.ID;
```

And then I get this error instead:

```
ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'OLD.estoque.ID_PRODUTO' in 'where clause'
SQL Statement:
DELETE FROM `papelaria`.`produto` WHERE (`ID` = '6')
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

P.S.: Not sure if it's worth mentioning but I'm fairly new to sql and programming in general, so I'd appreciate it if you took it into consideration when answering (for all purposes, just assume I don't know anything about anything ^^)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify, why 1. you need the dummy record in estoque table 2. why you cannot use FK ON DELETE CASCADE to delete records in estoque table while you delete records in produto?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your FK to:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_Estoque_Produto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PRODUTO`) 
    REFERENCES `produto` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then you will not need the before delete trigger any longer as records in `estoque` table will be deleted automatically.

Similar, adding `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will solve your 'update issue' in case someone update record's PK.

Still not sure why you'd like to have the dummy records in the `estoque` table.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. I couldn't alter the foreign key so I had to drop it and create a new one with both a cascade delete and a cascade update.

The reason I didn't do this before was simply because I didn't know what cascading was haha
Like I said, I'm new to sql and programming in general.
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Also, what exactly is a dummy record? Does it mean unnecessary data?
 
To clarify, `produto` is a table to keep track of all existing products. `estoque` is an inventory table just so I know how many products I have available for a future sale.

Are you saying I should perhaps drop the `estoque` table altogether and just add a `quantity` column to the `product` table? Would that be a better, cleaner way of designing my database?

Comment: Under dummy record I meant the record in estoque table you are adding from trigger while adding new product. I would not do this. No information in estoque table == product not available. However, your real app may expect zeroes to be returned so then you will need to change 'get' query or to have the dummy records as you do now. I do not know what would be better for you: keep quantity in separate table as you do or as a product.column. I prefer to keep stock's info not in item's table. P.S Feel free to 'accept' answer if it solves your issue.